# iOS: UILabel countdown hangs on other UI operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uilabel, countdown

I'm implementing a countdown with its value displayed on a UILabel, but have run into a problem. Here's the simplified code:

```
self.countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(countdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)countdown {          
     self.countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[self.countdownLabel.text intValue]-1];

     // Handle time out
     if ([self.countdownLabel.text intValue] == 0) {
             [self.countdownTimer invalidate];
             self.countdownTimer = nil;
     }
}
```

It works fine, but **if I do other UI operations in the viewcontroller, like scroll a scrollview, the timer hangs** as the scrollview scrolls and then boosts up to make up for the idle moments.

I tried dispatching the updating of the label to a background queue which of course didn't work.

```
dispatch_queue_t bgQ = dispatch_queue_create("bgQ", 0);
dispatch_async(bgQ, ^{
    self.countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[self.countdownLabel.text intValue]-1];
});
```

**What would be the solution here?**

Comment: UIKit should always be called on the main thread.

Comment: I know, just wanted a dirty solution... How would I make it so that it doesn't hang, though?

Comment: NSTimer plugs into the run loop, which UIScrollView takes over (that and there's some tiling and little tricks it does for optimization's sake.  Unfortunately, there really isn't a good way to do this.  I'd just live with it, as it's the behavior found in every app in your current situation (Tweetbot, Twitterific, and Netbot all seem to have this problem).

Comment: @Zoltán To quote myself: "UIKit should always be called on the main thread."

Comment: @CodaFi wow I thought this was a trivial matter

Comment: @H2CO3 that still leaves me with the hanging problem :)

Comment: @ZoltánMatók Did you try it? In your place I wouldn't expect the framework operate correctly if I didn't even bother using it according to its documentation.

Comment: You can try to redo UIScrollView with a CAScrollLayer.  I'm not quite sure about how iOS would do it, but I hacked a CVDisplayLink to a layer once.  That updates and scrolls on a background thread.

Comment: one thing you could do is make your time calculation be based of an nsdate and then on firs touch (`touchesBegan`) you can disable the timer and reschedule another one after touches end.. this wouldnt fix the hang, but it would get rid of the boost and start of the correct time instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(countdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];    
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.countdownTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Remember that in your countdown method you need an escape to invalidate your countdownTimer.

The timer will start without fire instruction when the

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.countdownTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

line is executed.
ABSOLUTELY no dispatch async for UI changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, you can dispatch_async to the main thread.  It's not forbidden in every case.

Comment: Hey this works fine, thank you!
I have

    // Handle time out
    if ([self.countdownLabel.text intValue] == 0) {
        [self.countdownTimer invalidate];
        self.countdownTimer = nil;

in the countdown method, that should be enough to invalidate it.

Do I need to do something with the runloop when I invalidate the timer?

Comment: yes CodaFi, i meant never async on queue different than main queue.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0 syntax**

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
```